# Access collection object on current page w will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

Tech specs: ruby 2.1.5p273, Rails 4.2.3.

I'm using the will_paginate gem to paginate my model on the page. Is it possible to be able to access the instances of the model that are being printed on the current page?

In the Projects controller:

```
@paginate_projects = @projects.keys.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 7)
```

Using Pry, I can get:

```
$ @paginate_projects.current_page => 2
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
$ @paginate_projects.current_page.projects => [Project #8, Project #9, Project #10, Project #11, Project #12, Project #13, Project #14]
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I did look over this: 
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mislav/will_paginate/WillPaginate/Collection

Comment: The `paginate` method returns an `ActiveRecordRelation` from your model. It's like an `array` of objects that you can traverse and manipulate. Didn't understand your question really.

Comment: Hi @MurifoX, I want to be able to access that array of objects for the current_page only. Do you know how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of paginating on `@projects.keys` (I'm not sure what this would return), I recommend paginating `@projects` (or possibly `Project`) directly.

When you call `#paginate` on a model, or on an ActiveRecord collection or scope, it returns the records for that page only.

Let's say, in your controller, you do:

```
@projects = Project.some_scope_or_query
@paginate_projects = @projects.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7)
```

In your view / template, the `@paginate_projects` variable will contain the current page's worth of projects only.

Personally, I'd recommend paginating on the model directly, unless you have particularly complicated logic going on in the controller. Something like:

```
@projects = Project.some_scope_or_query
                     .paginate(page: params[:page],
                               per_page: 7)
```

In your view, you would use `@projects` as your record collection.

Answer (score -2):

I've never used `will_paginate` gem but I believe the `@paginate_projects` it's your ActiveRecord relation of projects with some additional methods.

From link that you provided:

> Arrays returned from paginating finds are, in fact, instances of this
>   little class. You may think of WillPaginate::Collection as an ordinary
>   array with some extra properties. Those properties are used by view
>   helpers to generate correct page links.